# Customize Approval Report fields

Tags: reporting, approval-process

We are starting to run Leads through an Approval process and want to report on them (of course!).

Is it possible to show **other fields** on the report than the one Related To?
It shows the **Lead Name, which is not  relevant** to our process - **Company** is the meaningful field. 
Others would be nice, too. 
Any work around appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What report type are you using for this?

Comment: I have used Custom report type on ProcessInstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jaw999

The issue you are having is that ProcessInstance.targetObjectId is a polymorphic relationship to other sObjects (including Lead in your example) and OOB SFDC reports won't let you build a custom report type that will traverse that polymorphic lookup relationship

Assuming you need a report like the ones in the [SFDC help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approval_history_reports_examples.htm&language=en_US) , I'd suggest you write a Visualforce page / controller that executed two SOQL to populate a single inner class for whatever reporting output you want

The VF page can be launched from a home page custom link in the sidebar

**Query 1**

```
  SELECT Id, targetObjectId, (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps)
    FROM ProcessInstance where ...
  save results in a map of targetObjectId to ProcessInstance and
  save results in a map of ProcessInstanceId to targetObjectId
```

**Query 2**

```
 Select id, company, email, lastname from Lead 
    where id IN targetObjIdToPIMap.keySet()
```

Lastly, merge results of the Query2 with the maps from Query1 into a list of some inner class containing your reporting data. Use VF pageBlockTable/dataTable/repeat to construct a pleasing format

Details of writing the actual VF page/controller are left as an exercise to you

Comment: Understood. I guess the logical development would be a report type that starts with Leads (or other object) and could choose then as children the approval objects.

Comment: yes, except you can't define such a report type as of V32

Comment: I know, it's the first solution I tried.